# JMeter plugin DbMon Sample Collector on oracle

Tags: oracle, jmeter, database-connection, jmeter-plugins

I want to check oracle database performance over JMeter test,

JMeter plugin [DbMon Sample Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DbMon/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=DbMon) offer to plot

> performance counters accessible via sql

It give SQLServer example (which I didn't find any reference to such variables)

I want to know if it can be used in Oracle and how? or should I use other mechanism for check oracle performance on test run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be used on Oracle but the user must have access to sys tables / views.

For monitoring counters, it’s a large subject still start with:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/monitoring002.htm#ADMIN11255
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-to-find-the-latest-sql-statements-within-the-database

And of course you need to add oracle jdbc driver compatible with your oracle version

Comment: Thank you for answering, still I don't know what are the "performance counters" in oracle?